# Basis of multivariate polynomials with a specified set of roots

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials

I'm studying certain polynomials of 2 complex variables, say x and y. These polynomials have roots at the non-negative integers, that is both $x$ and $y$ have to be

$x,y \in \mathbb{N}$

simultaneously with the restriction that

$x+y \leq A$

for some non-negative integer A. I'd like to know the basis for these polynomials of *minimal* total degree (sum of degrees in $x$ and $y$), up to overal constants. I think this basis is:

$\left(x \atop n\right)\left(y \atop A+1-n\right)$

for integer $n$ with $0 \leq n \leq A+1$. The brackets are falling factorials:

$\left(x \atop n\right) = x (x-1)....(x-n-1)$

with
$\left(x \atop 0\right)\equiv 1$

At the moment I have only a proof-by-lack-of-imagination argument that this is the full set. Of course, I'd also like to know how to generalize to multiple complex variables :)

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "total degree" of a finite set of polynomials? The maximum of their (total) degrees, the sum of their degrees...

Comment: the sum of $i$ and $j$ in term of the type $x^i y^j$

Comment: No, I mean, you want to compare different sets of generators; how should we define the "total degree" of such a set? I know what is the "total degree" of a polynomial, but here you're asking how to compare *sets* of them if I am understanding the question correctly.

Comment: The question is about the "set of these (polynomials of minimal total degree)", not "(set of these polynomials) of minimal total degree".

Comment: edited for clarification... apologies for not thinking like a mathematician :)

Comment: So, just to make sure I'm getting you right: You want to show that $\dbinom{x}{n}\dbinom{y}{A+1-n}$ for $n$ ranging over $\left\lbrace 0,1,...,A+1 \right\rbrace$ form a basis of the vector space of polynomials in $x$ and $y$ of total degree $\leq A+1$ which vanish on all $\left(x,y\right)\in\mathbb N^2$ satisfying $x+y\leq A$ ?

Comment: Hint (I believe): The fact that these polynomials are linearly independent is clear (because $\dbinom{x}{n}\dbinom{y}{m}$ are linearly independent for $n$ and $m$ both ranging over the nonnegative integers). Remains to check that they span. Prove this by induction over $A$. In the induction step, you are starting with a polynomial $p$ of total degree $\leq A+1$ which vanishes on all $\left(x,y\right)\in\mathbb N^2$ satisfying $x+y\leq A$. By subtracting an appropriate linear combination of the polynomials $\dbinom{x}{n}\dbinom{y}{A+1-n}$, you can get rid of all monomials of total ...

Comment: ... degree $A+1$ (because the highest terms of $\dbinom{x}{n}\dbinom{y}{A+1-n}$ are $\dfrac{x^n}{n!}\cdot\dfrac{y^{A+1-n}}{\left(A+1-n\right)!}$, and these clearly span all monomials of total degree $A+1$), while not violating the condition that $p$ vanishes on all $\left(x,y\right)\in\mathbb N^2$ satisfying $x+y\leq A$. Now that the total degree is down to $\leq A$, you can apply the induction hypothesis.